# How to open multiple pdf filesusing pdf plumber in Python?

Tags: python, excel, pdf

I have a folder full of pdf files. I need to iterate through each of the pdf files according to the given condition. Using pandas its not possible. Is there any method to iterate through each files using pdfplumber?

```
import os
import glob
import shutil
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import xlrd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import time
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
import numpy as np
from tabula import read_pdf
import tabula
import requests
import pdfplumber
from tabula import read_pdf

glob.glob("C:/Users/Dreamer/Desktop/test_run/machine/*.pdf")



#THIS IS THE CONDITION I WANT TO IMPLEMENT IN EACH FILE

with pdfplumber.open(path) as pdf:
    page = pdf.pages[0]
    text = page.extract_text()

for row in text.split('\n'):
    if row.startswith('Raumtemperatur '):
        jobstart = row.split()[-2]
        jobend   = row.split()[-1]
print("jobstart", jobstart) 
print("jobstart", jobend)
```

Looking forward for solution or an alternative :)

Comment: pass the pdf_path by iterating over the glob to the with block's path?

Comment: Yeah, using the 'with' blocks logic to each of the pdf files in that folder :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC,

```
import glob
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
for current_pdf_file in tqdm(glob.glob("C:/Users/Dreamer/Desktop/test_run/machine/*.pdf")):
    with pdfplumber.open(current_pdf_file) as my_pdf:
         # do other things here?
```